# How to use Sennheiser e945 mic as input for Smartphone

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, wireless, transmitter, smartphone

I have [Sennheiser e945 microphone](https://en-in.sennheiser.com/e-945). It says it is a Dynamic microphone.
I have OnePlus 7/8T phones and have been trying to figure out how to use the mic for singing and recording (wirelessly) directly to my smartphone apps.

Based on google search and [this article](https://mynewmicrophone.com/how-to-connect-an-external-microphone-to-a-smartphone/), i understood that i need an XLR to Bluetooth transmitter.

Q1. Would XLR to Bluetooth transmitter work for this ?
Q2. Or, do I need phantom power in case of Sennheiser e945 microphone ?
Q3. Would the volume be low or noise be high when I use this XLR to Bluetooth transmitter ?
Q4. Any example of some good XLR to Bluetooth transmitters ? (i know this forum is not for recommending any product but this would help me analyze and understand the attributes of good solutions to my problem)

(I do not know much about music equipment and googled to figure out whatever i mentioned above).

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange generally doesn't like multiple questions, however, as these are all pretty tightly related...

> Q1. Would XLR to Bluetooth transmitter work for this ?

A1. For a given definition of 'work' yes. You may not get the best sound & you may suffer latency [delay between mic & phone] & signal drop-outs.

> Q2. Or, do I need phantom power in case of Sennheiser e945 microphone ?

A2. Dynamic mics don't use phantom.

> Q3. Would the volume be low or noise be high when I use this XLR to Bluetooth transmitter ?

A3. Presumably like many other fields - you get what you pay for. Bluetooth is very much a consumer-level structure & I wouldn't rely on it for pro audio.

> Q4. Any example of some good XLR to Bluetooth transmitters ?

A4. Sorry, no. Not an area I have ever considered researching.

The hardware route - as mentioned in Martin's answer - would always be preferable, unless you're rich.

For a rather shocking comparison check out [Amazon 'XLR to Bluetooth'](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=xlr%20to%20bluetooth&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) vs **actual** pro audio transmitter systems, for on-stage, TV studio or location recording etc. Stockist chosen at random from Google search [Location Sound Corp](https://www.locationsound.com/wireless-108/transmitters-126)

Answer (score 1):

You need an audio interface. Check out “Roland”or “IK Multimedia” or “Rode” or “Apogee” for suitable interfaces. The mic is dynamic so doesn’t require phantom power.